# Explaining proper meaning of columns to Google Sheets chart editor

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I'm trying to make a simple chart displaying the number of events that occurred each month in X years. This means I want a chart that shows:

1. X colored lines, one for every year
2. Month names marked on the X axis
3. Event counts on the Y axis

[image: graph drawn in MS Paint]

[My table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1888_AdQolHLw9mVU2cVpqQEVSjP-j4FNWnSH6OIvyM8/edit?usp=sharing) looks (it's Czech but I suppose it's comprehensible) like this:

[image: Google Sheets screenshot]

I tried all I could think off, but the chart keeps putting years on X axis and sometimes produces a total mess.

If I select [`Table`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHs1Q.png) option in the chart editor, I get this mess:

[image: click for JSFiddle link]

Is the chart even capable of rendering what I want?

I mean, my request is quite basic I'd say - so how come it took me so long and it still doesn't work?

Comment: @pnuts to the rescue and +1 for the drawings !!

Comment: btw, are you using a script to create the chart? If so, please add the tag

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra no, I'm using their GUI editor. I may have chosen wrong title phrasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all your data including labels and insert a Line chart. Then in Chart Editor check *Switch rows/columns*, *Use column A as headers* and *Use row 1 as labels*:

[image: WA71257 example]

Comment: Thanks it worked. I wonder why didn't I see the "*Switch rows/columns option before*"